# How to publish multiple collections in single subscription call in meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteorite, meteor-publications

I this possible to publish multiple collections in single subscription call? if so please guide me.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code snippet you tried to use. It would help people answering your question greatly! Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @methode. Thanks mate. I will follow

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. A [publish](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) function can return an array of cursors. For example:

**client**

```js
Meteor.subscribe('roomAndMessages');
```

**server**

```js
Meteor.publish("roomAndMessages", function (roomId) {
  check(roomId, String);
  return [
    Rooms.find({_id: roomId}),
    Messages.find({roomId: roomId})
  ];
});
```

**important note**

> If you return multiple cursors in an array, they currently must all be from different collections. We hope to lift this restriction in a future release.

Comment: Instead of returning an array, you also could create a "virtual" collection which you setup in your own publishing method. To filter those docs you are able to use arguments on publish/subscribe. If you just want to have complex documents to display content this may a smart solution. If you want to use the collection also for updates on db, an array result is mostly easier to implement. Cheers, Tom